# How to ensure new object is not destroyed in local function?

Tags: c++

I have a class object which stores another class object array.  I used to use the direct object in the map, but now I changed it to pointers because storing the object directly behaved strange when trying to use the `map.erase()` function.  The problem with pointers is that I don't know how to keep the objects alive when created locally.  Is there a way to ensure that an object does not auto delete when created locally in a function?

```
class F{
    public:
       <stuff here>
};
class Delta{
    public:
        map<int, F*> faces;
        void init(){
            F newFace; // <- does declaring this locally automatically destroy it?
                       // the pointer gets stored, but the object seems to get deleted after init()
            faces[0] = &newFace;
        }
        void do_stuff(){
            for(auto it : faces){
                F face = *it.second;
                // face seems to be lost
            }
        }
};
```

EDIT -- map `map<>h_` has the expected behavior of removing the key, value in the map.  `map<>h` (with the F object) does not.  Is there a way to erase a pair with an object in a map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class F{
    public:
        F(){};
        ~F(){};
        double value;
};
int main(){
    map<int, F> h;
    F ff1;
    ff1.value = 200.0;
    F ff2;
    ff2.value = 400.0;
    F ff3;
    ff3.value = 800.0;
    h[0] = ff1;
    h[1] = ff2;
    h[2] = ff3;

    h.erase(1);

    cout << "h[1] " << h[1].value << endl;


    map<int, double> h_;
    double ff1_ = 200.0;
    double ff2_ = 400.0;
    double ff3_ = 800.0;
    h_[0] = ff1_;
    h_[1] = ff2_;
    h_[2] = ff3_;

    h_.erase(1);

    cout << "h_[1] " << h_[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
h[1] 400
h_[1] 0
```

Comment: Use a `map<int, F>` instead of `map<int, F*>` and then you don't need to worry about it

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<F>>`

Comment: " I changed it to pointers because storing the object directly behaved strange when trying to use the map.erase() function" -- probably no strangeness but just a lack of understanding. That is what you should ask a question about, including a [mcve] and both expected and "strange" behaviour that you observed.

Comment: @Genjutsu: That doesn't really help with the problem, though it is generally good advise. Better though is to use a non-pointer value type.

Comment: You can't.  But you were close with your pointer-based approach.  `faces[0] = new Face();` will create a new Face on the heap.  (Of course, people frown on manual management of pointers because they're very easy to mismanage, as everyone will attest to.)  I suggest you go back to the value types though, and figure out what went wrong with your original approach.

Comment: I did performance testing, and I found for complex objects, using std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr was WAY more performant. So all my vectors storing objects store smart pointers to those objects.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Something's wrong with X (`map<int, F>`) so help me with Y (`map<int, F*>`).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated it

Comment: @Genjutsu I would much rather work with the actual object in the map than unique pointers.

Comment: As far as I know, just using the `operator[]` on a map also inserts a `std::pair` to the map. So after deleting the second element in ` h_.erase(1);` you are calling `[]` in `h_[1]` and inserting a pair like (1, 0.0).

Comment: That's not a [mcve], please read that link! Also, you now just added a second independent question to your question, which doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Also, no one knows what is going on in class `F`. Therefore it's hard to track the problem. Another note is that you better use `at`. Like `h.at(1).value`, however, keep in mind that if the key doesn't exist then `at` will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception. So you have to use a `try-catch` too.

Comment: @alvrm It's not necessarily desirable. But in this case, you probably need to switch to `at` since the behavior of `operator[]` may cause problems for your use case. As I said, `[]` also inserts an element if the key does not exist in the map.

Comment: @digito_evo Apparently it does create a new F object when I index the map.  This was the error in my code; and it also seemed to assign the old/deleted F object to the newly created on which really threw me off.  I think I can figure out the problem using ```try``` and ```at```.  Appreciate it

Comment: @alvrm Glad to hear that. Now speaking of `[]`, yes it calls the constructor of `F` and creates a new instance of `F` only if the given key does not exist in the map.

Comment: @alvrm Although I'm not sure why the old value stays there after the erase. Maybe it creates the new `F` object at the old memory location and since you have set the `value` to e.g. 400.0, the new object gets the ownership of that value. You have to keep in mind that automatic variables are not deleted until the end of their scope is reached. e.g. if `value` is a `double` stored on the stack it might keep its original value after going out of scope until something else is written to that stack location.

Answer (score 0):

For your code with `map<int, F>`, the problem is that your `F::F()` constructor does not initialize the `value` field, so it gets whatever bits happened to be in memory whenever you create a new F object.  If you want to look at the `value`, you need to explicitly set it to something.  Using

```
F() { value = 0.0; }
```

in the class would do the trick.

Comment: Or `F() : value{ 0.0 } { }`